# .then return always a promise object, how save the result in a variable?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

Hello i don't succeed to resolve this promise, can you help me to understand my mistake ?

```
export const onReadTranslationData = () => {
  const translations = database()
    .ref('/languages')
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      const languages = { en: snapshot.child('en').val(), tr: snapshot.child('tr').val() };
    });
  return translations;
};
```

when i try to console.log(translations) it always give me a promise object.

Why it returns always a promise objects ?

Comment: Because a promise will be assigned to translations. Do you want to print the languages?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning a promise you have to use `.then` to get the result

```js
export const onReadTranslationData = () => {
  const translations = database()
    .ref('/languages')
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      const languages = { en: snapshot.child('en').val(), tr: snapshot.child('tr').val() };
    });
  return translations;
};

translations.then((results) => {
  console.log('translations: ', results)
})
```